# Omission of articles

Tags: grammar, articles

I came across this sentence: The function changes the size, position, and Z order of a child, pop-up, or top-level window.

I would write it this way: The function changes the size, the position, and the Z order of a child, a pop-up, or a top-level window.

Is there a rule or a convention to omit articles when there are more words
in a list?

Comment: It's a stylistic choice. But my guess is yours is a *minority* preference. Particularly when you're doing it *twice* (actually, *six* times, in two different ways) within the same sentence. It just comes across as stilted.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Please consider posting your comment as an answer. My guess is that this question is a common one for non-native English speakers. (It might even be a duplicate; dunno.)

Comment: @Drew: I might have posted an actual answer if this had been asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but not here (although I haven't closevoted, I still might vote for migration).

Comment: Migration would be good, I think. But there are lots of folks who speak or write English quite well who could benefit from this Q&A, IMO. Some of them might not frequent ELL.

Comment: @Drew ELU is not intended to be all things (English) to all people (whatever their level of English). And FF hopefully considers a 'My guess ... ' statement inadequate as an answer.

Comment: As FF says, both are correct. I'd agree with his comment totally. But this shouldn't be seen as the preferred choice in all contexts. 'The car, the motorcycle and the cycle are the most usual means of getting about on Mann' sounds better than the deleted form, and 'The Lion, Witch and Wardrobe' just wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.

@EdwinAshworth The second sentence sounded rigid and repetitive for me, too, but I was not aware of any rule that permits the omission of articles in such a case. A styllistic choice in a particular context? Hmm, how can you then decide if you are in doubt? I can't rely on a feeling or what sounds good for me.

Comment: Welcome to English.  Those of us who feel semi-competent in making such judgement calls have been around a long time and listened to and read a lot, encountering a lot of examples. Then we argue amongst ourselves over the trickier ones. The fact that you're asking about such nuanced differences means you're not doing too badly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English is better off when more brief; for that is the power of the English Language: always aim for shorter sentences especially if the language is not poetic or adhered to any metric or particular style. In the case of your fixed sentence, the addition of those articles extends the sentence unnecessarily and makes it sound extremely explanatory as if in slow motion and being elucidated to a child or an elderly person.

Comment: Your definition is irrelevant, as it refers to article in the sense of a section of a document. The question was about a quite different sense of "article". 
Furthermore, personal opinions are not really on topic in answers on this site.

Comment: Fixed it.. I pasted the wrong definition and didn't check. Thanks!